# How would I call images from a folder to use in my slideshow using php

Tags: php, arrays, slideshow

I can't seam to find an answer to my specific issue.

I have the slideshow already, I don't need to create one. I know that I would need to create an array and run a for each loop to get the images in the slideshow.

All I need to know is how do I create an array using the contents of a folder, in this case images. I can't find clear answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glob` function:

```
<?php
foreach(glob('*.jpg') as $image) {
    echo $image; // will print file name;
}
```